# Is Ubuntu Desktop shipped with C packages and compilers ? How and where can I check all the available C headers?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I'm moving from Mac Os to Linux Ubuntu and I wanted to know if Ubuntu is shipped with a C compiler and C packages. Where can I check the list of all available c headers ?

Comment: The dpkg command can list the installed packages

Answer (score 2):

Not by default. But you can install all you need to develop with one command

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

That will setup all the tools you need to start coding.

System headers are typically installed under `/usr/include`

You can list all them with

```
find /usr/include
```